# What does a questionmark "?" in the CSS-url() function mean?

Tags: css, url, parameters, background-image

I've got a CSS class like this.:

```
.myclass {
    background-image: url("../images/icons/myicon.png?version=8")
}
```

As far as i know questionmarks are used to address HTTP-GET parameters. Despite research its hard to get a clue about the version parameter `myicon.png?version=8` in this context.

What does it mean and for what is it used for?

Comment: It's the same thing. The query string is part of the URL. A URL is a URL no matter where it appears.

Comment: It's to prevent caching, if you change the value of `version` your browser needs to download the 'new version' instead of loading the cached version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is used to avoid usage of old version of **css** or other files once they get updated.

E.g. if you're running a website with `style.css` called in head section. This file has a **cache** validity of 1 year.

Now you plan to make changes to this file and publish the new version. Once the new visitors come to the site, they see the new version. However all the **returning** visitor within the 1 year will see the previous css file as it's already cached in their browsers cache.

To prevent this issue and issue with vairous **CDN** caching your files too, the versioning method is used. This results in unique file identity once it's changed.

Answer (score 5):

You are correct. It requires that URL with parameter `version=8`.

Usually it's *no-cache* method adding some parameter to URL - telling browser that you want to get non-cached version of this URL.

Or in some advanced applications it may have some other meaning.